# java, JSTL and getting values by key

Tags: java, foreach, jstl, hashtable

I would like to know why I am not able to get values from an outer hashtable using the keys in jstl, the keys are integer values, the values are inner hashtables and I am working on some legacy code hence the reason for the Hashtables, which are returned from a stored procedure call in this form.

Oddly in the inner hashtable as I process it in my forEach loop I am able to get those values out... `${data['NAME']}` actually does work.

I am able to loop over the entire outer hashtable using JSTL forEach loop and its ok but if I try to get a value like `${missing_ciphers[1]}` or even `${missing_ciphers['1']}` then nothing is returned.

The hashtable when printed looks like this:

```
{4={SOURCE=D, NAME=D}, 3={SOURCE=C, NAME=C}, 2={SOURCE=B, NAME=B},   1={SOURCE=A, NAME=A}}
```

I am able to loop over it ok using the following code but the list is not in the order I want it to be in so I wanted to use the loop counter to get objects out by their key but this doesnt seem to return anything (the inline styles will be moved into a css file once I have this working as I want...):

```
<c:forEach items="${missing_ciphers}" var="ciphers" varStatus="cipher_loop">

                        <c:set var="data" value="${ciphers.value}">
                        </c:set>

                        <tr style="border-left: none; border-right: none;" class="${cipher_loop.index % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">
                            <td><span style="font-weight: bold;">${data['SOURCE']}</span></td>
                            <td><span style="font-weight: bold;">${data['NAME']}</span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
```

Can anyone help me understand what is happening here and why I am not able to get a value out using the `${missing_ciphers[1]}` type syntax?

I should add that the following code does print the inner hashtable into the tomcat console:

`<% System.out.println("val: " + ((Hashtable)request.getAttribute("missing_ciphers")).get(1)); %>`

I have even tried the following just to see if it was down to the type of the key this still doesnt get from the outer hashtable:

```
<c:forEach items="${missing_ciphers}" var="ciphers" varStatus="cipher_loop">
                        <c:set var="counter" value="${cipher_loop.index + 1}" />
                        <fmt:parseNumber var="fmt_counter" integerOnly="true" type="number" value="${counter}" />
                        <c:out value="${fmt_counter}" />

                        <c:set var="data" value="${missing_ciphers[fmt_counter]}"></c:set>

                        <tr style="border-left: none; border-right: none;" class="${cipher_loop.index % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">
                            <td><span style="font-weight: bold;">${data['SOURCE']}</span></td>
                            <td><span style="font-weight: bold;">${data['NAME']}</span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using variable name assigned to varStatus - 'cipher_loop' and not varStatus itself.

Also you should use the index property or the count property to get the current index. (index starts at 0 and count at 1 by default)

```
${missing_ciphers[varStatus]}

should be 

${missing_ciphers[cipher_loop.count]}
```

### Edit

What is the type of your key in your outer hastable? Integer?

The type of varStatus.index (or counter) is long and you will have to explicitly set it as integer to use it as a key of your outer table

The following code works for me

```
<jsp:directive.page import="java.util.*"/>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%

Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
Hashtable h1 = new Hashtable();h1.put("SOURCE","D");h1.put("NAME","D");
Hashtable h2 = new Hashtable();h2.put("SOURCE","C");h2.put("NAME","C");
Hashtable h3 = new Hashtable();h3.put("SOURCE","B");h3.put("NAME","B");
Hashtable h4 = new Hashtable();h4.put("SOURCE","A");h4.put("NAME","A");
h.put(4,h1);h.put(3,h2);h.put(2,h3);h.put(1,h1);


request.setAttribute("missing_ciphers",h);

%>


<c:forEach items="${missing_ciphers}" var="ciphers" varStatus="cipher_loop">
        <c:set var="counter" value="${cipher_loop.index + 1}" />
        <c:out value = "${counter}"/>
        <c:set var = 'counter' value = '<%=new Integer(pageContext.findAttribute("counter").toString())%>'/>

        <c:set var="data" value="${missing_ciphers[counter]}"></c:set>


                        <tr>
                            <td><span style="font-weight: bold;">${data['SOURCE']}</span></td>
                            <td><span style="font-weight: bold;">${data['NAME']}</span></td>
                        </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

OTOH, if the keys in your table is of type long, then you can use the varstatus.index property directly

```
<jsp:directive.page import="java.util.*"/>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%

Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
Hashtable h1 = new Hashtable();h1.put("SOURCE","D");h1.put("NAME","D");
Hashtable h2 = new Hashtable();h2.put("SOURCE","C");h2.put("NAME","C");
Hashtable h3 = new Hashtable();h3.put("SOURCE","B");h3.put("NAME","B");
Hashtable h4 = new Hashtable();h4.put("SOURCE","A");h4.put("NAME","A");
h.put(new Long(4),h1);h.put(new Long(3),h2);h.put(new Long(2),h3);h.put(new Long(1),h1);


request.setAttribute("missing_ciphers",h);

%>
test


<<c:forEach items="${missing_ciphers}" var="ciphers" varStatus="cipher_loop">
        <c:set var="counter" value="${cipher_loop.index + 1}" />


        <c:set var="data" value="${missing_ciphers[counter]}"></c:set>
        ${data}
                        <tr>
                            <td><span style="font-weight: bold;">${data['SOURCE']}</span></td>
                            <td><span style="font-weight: bold;">${data['NAME']}</span></td>
                        </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Hi Sorry that wasnt supposed to be part of my example... I replaced it anyway with your code which did nothing, I then tried ${missing_ciphers[cipher_loop.index + 1]} because the index is what I am using for my alternate row shading which works, that also doesnt return anything from the hashtable.